# Get product custom field related to Woocommerce order items

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to add data from custom field in front of the subtotal on the checkout/order, but the `get_post_meta` is not display. I have tried `$product->get_ID()`, `$post_id` and `get_the_ID()`.

```
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_formatted_line_subtotal', 'custom_field_test');


function bmc_test($subtotal){ 
    global $woocommerce;
    global $item_id;
    //echo $values['price_currency'];

    //just tried to see if it I could get display
    wc_get_order_item_meta($item);


    $custom_field =  get_post_meta( $values['product_id'], 'custom_field', true );
    return  $custom_field . ' '. $subtotal;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some missing arguments and some mistakes in your code… Try the following instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_formatted_line_subtotal', 'custom_field_test', 10, 3 );
function custom_field_test( $subtotal, $item, $order ){ 
    $product = $item->get_product(); // The instance of the WC_Product Object

    if( $custom_field =  get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'custom_field', true ) ) {
        $subtotal = $custom_field . ' '. $subtotal;
    }
    return $subtotal;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: I get this error twice:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function custom_field_test(), 1 passed in

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME!! Thank you!